# Product data table hidden

Tags: plugins

I am facing some issues with my companys website. The company sells online courses on their website, and they have several products(courses), with their data such as date when the product will start, live stock level and cost of the course. All this information is included inside the product data table. Since last week, I cant see the product data table of the website, and because of that I cant change the dates, cost or anything in the present course. I have tried researching online, but couldn`t find any solutions. I have checked each settings inside wordpress, even the user permissions, but nothing works. Can somebody please tell me what happened and how to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you can't see it in the admin dashboard, or do you mean a table in the database and you're looking directly in the site's database and it's gone from there?

Comment: This sounds like it's a problem with the plugins you've used to set up the storefront and the courses. You should talk to whoever wrote those plugins in the first instance please.

Comment: If this is a table in the admin site and you want to debug this yourself you'll need to find the menu item you used to use for the product table and debug why it isn't appearing; or if you have a bookmark to the page you can debug why that isn't working for you anymore; or if you can find the PHP file that implements this table you can read that too and work out what permission checks it's making.

Comment: Hi Danish, to assist with your issues we are going to need more insight in your installation. Please include code snippets and plugin names, because without that we cannot debug or research the issue.